# TFS Reporting Services Configuration Error - The RPC Server is Unavailable

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, wmi, rpc

I'm trying to configure Team Foundation Reporting but without any success.

The App Tier and the Data Tier are in separate servers.

I guess it's not a port/firewall problem, because I opened port 135, and I can see the established connection by using TCPView (from Sysinternals) whenever I click "Populate URLs" in the Reports tab in TFS Administration Console. I can also telnet servername 135 without any problems.

I also checked if WMI service is started in the Data-Tier. And for SQL Server Reporting Services. Also checked for RPC and RPC Locator in both servers. They're all started and automatic.

I also set tfs app user as admin in sql reporting services. Added all kinds of permissions to the tfs user in the Data-Tier server.

I set all user permissions in dcomcnfg.

Allowed all WMI namespaces permissions to the user. (Computer Management -> WMI Control)

Deactivated Windows Firewall in both servers temporarily.

No luck.

However, in the app-tier, when I click Computer Management -> Connect to another computer, and type the data-tier IP, i can't connect. I get the message "Computer xxx cannot be managed. The network path was not found". How is that ? Tried IP, name, and FQDN. I also tried browsing and selecting the computer. Nothing changed.

I'm lost, what could possibly be happening ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer:

[IIS to SQL Server kerberos auth issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618552/iis-to-sql-server-kerberos-auth-issues/5145571#5145571)

which links to an old but user-friendly troubleshooting web app called [DelegConfig](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1887). It can try to run the [SetSpn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773257%28WS.10%29.aspx) commands for you, at least giving you an idea of what they need to be.

I ran into SPN issues when using an externally-accessible URL (+SSL) everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

i'm betting that you're having the double-hop issue.  try having your system admin set an spn for the website on the sql server.

Comment: Thanks for the response! You mean that issue from NTLM authentication? And which website? You mean the reporting services web service? Or tfs url? I don't know much of this stuff, sorry.

Comment: yeah, NTLM.  I'm not sure if it'd be the reports website or the actual tfs website, or both.  sorry, i really don't know a whole lot about this myself or i would have been more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

you also need the AD permission 'trust for delegation' on the AD Service Account, right?

do that and SetSpn with the service account, that should help I think that the SPN option was spot on

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same issue. Kind of as it worked, when I turned off the firewall. Turns out the Firewall rules for WMI on the report server make the difference and the population of Report Server URLs in DevOps Setup dialog work:

[image]