# Impersonation on remote service says Login failed for user 'NT Authority\Anonymous Logon'

Tags: c#, sql-server, impersonation, windows-identity

I have a service that I want to when accessing databases I want to access databases
to use the calling identities credentials.

Before I access a particular database I do an impersonation by

```
var winId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
var ctx = winId.Impersonate();
//Access Database
ctx.Undo();
```

This scenario works fine when the service runs locally on my PC. However when deployed on another remote PC I get the error:

> Login failed for user 'NT Authority\Anonymous Logon"

as soon as it tries to access the database.

I have been told by DBAdmin that the SQL Server has an SPN.

The account under which the service runs under is a domain account.

Comment: Windows service or web service hosted on IIS?

Comment: It has .asmx extension so I guess that is webservice. DB Team have advised me this is thee error they are getting when Im trying to access the database

DESCRIPTION: SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while 
establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been 
closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates 
the cause of failure.  [CLIENT: 192.168.14.116].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706580/kerberos-double-hop-in-asp-net-4-0-sql2008r2/

Comment: You cannot double hop with windows authentication, only kerberos can do that.

Comment: So I need to re-write my asmx service following this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27554/Authentication-in-web-services-using-C-and-Kerbero

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you most likely experiencing is `Delegation` as opposed `Impersonation`.

I assume in your production environment you actually have your Web Browser, your IIS Server and SQL Server are all on different machines.

Simple Impersonation does not support `Multi-Hop`.

To support `Multi-Hop` you need to setup `Kerberos` with `Delegation`. You are going to have to setup the `SPN` records on your `Active Directory`. Once that is done, you also need to enable `Delgation` for the IIS machine on your AD.

In short, Delegation is a HUGE can of worms.

Comment: Yes we have done all of that except setting the IIS Server an SPN as I have been told this can be dangerous. II Server is still running under a local account, does this need to run under a AD account with an SPN set?

Comment: Either you need an AD account, and you set SPN on that or you use a local account and set SPN on the machine. Still. Kerberos Auth with multi hop is a black art. My final advise is DON'T. It's such a complicated system to debug.

Comment: What alternatives are there then? I need to access resources on another network using the person that's calling the service credentials.

Comment: Apart from re-architecture your program to avoid multi-hop auth? None. In .net/Windows Kerberos is the only way. As for your source telling you that 'setting SPN is dangerous'. Well consider what delegation means, the whole concept is a huge security hole. Hence to reduce the attack surface area, Kerberos Delegation is extremely complex and fragile.

Comment: Thanks, I assume the holes are someone can somehow sniff the delegation being sent around and emulate that? Thats why its dangerous? ANyway Im just wondering if its related to the way Im making my calls to the ASMX service so reading up on
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services2.requestsoapcontext.aspx

Comment: No and no. Delegation is only dangerous if you lose control of your IIS server.

Comment: Another issue is my ASMX service is running under a domain account. WHen this domain account has an SPN I cannot use my client application to authenticate again it anymore. How would I rectify this?

Comment: I keep on getting 401 authentication errors. I am calling multiple asmx web services and sometimes for whatever reason one succeeds whereas the other one fails but then for some reason one works then the other one fails...Have no idea what the reason is

Comment: Are your computers all NTP synchronized? Are you using FQDNs to access your server? Is Jupiter rising in the seventh house, on a blue moon during a solar flare?

Comment: Read Ken's writeup on Kerberos and IIS.  I recently did this same thing, and it's not all that bad once you understand how it all works.

http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2006/10/20/512.aspx

Comment: Thanks looks like I got a bit of reading to do, the funny thing is going through the browsers like IE and firefox the authentication works fine..Running the services locally the authentication also works fine. NTP seems synchronized. Not surw what FQDN is

Comment: Fully Qualified Domain Name

Comment: I'm still struggling with this...i have another post up for a bounty here if anyone is intersted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19806533/client-calling-multiple-asmx-services#comment29613892_19806533

Comment: Just wondering if IIS running under a local account matters? The service is running under a domain account but not IIS. Also there is only one service that is running under the domain account. There are other services that the wpf application calls but they run on different local accounts. Just wondering if this matters

Comment: The account that IIS is running under needs to be set in your SPN.

Comment: @TheWommies just realised the actual question you asked...YOU CANNOT RUN KERBEROS AGAINST A LOCAL ACCOUNT. The AD needs to send the User's credentials to IIS encrypted using the IIS account public keys. Only way it can do that is because it stores all AD user's public keys. You CAN force the `system` account to decrypt the user credentials by using `Kernel Mode Security`, and the `system` account is an AD account. However I never managed to get that to work...

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure IIS offers "Windows Authentication" authentication and it is enabled. By default the WindowsAuthenticationModule is not installed and Anonymous Authentication is used.

[image: Default]

To setup Windows Authentication use the Web Platform Installer and search for "Windows Authentication". After the installation completed, enable the "Windows Authentication" authentication for your site.

[image: After setup and enable]

See [Configure Windows Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information.

You might also take a look at the related questions on the right, especially 
[SQL Server returns error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." in Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462674/sql-server-returns-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon)

Comment: Yes windows authentication with no Anonymous authentication is set up so that anonymous is not enabled. I have read those posts, not still not sure what I am missing