# Getting IIS to impersonate the windows user to SQL server in an intranet environment

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, kerberos

I am developing an intranet site using C# and ASP.NET MVC. I have SQL Server on one machine and IIS running on a separate machine. I would like a user to visit the intranet site and without prompting the user internet explorer sends the users windows credentials to IIS and these are then passed to sql server meaning sql server can see the user accessing the database.

I am aware of the Kerberos double hop issue and it is this I am trying to get around. At present I can get IE to pass the windows credentials to IIS and authenticate fine. I just cannot get IIS to pass on those credentials to SQL Server and instead the request currently runs under the app pool identity which is set to a domain service account "htu\srv-htu-iis".

My setup is as follows:

**Web.Config**

```xml
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

**Connection String**

```
connection string=&quot;data source=hturesbsqlp01;initial catalog=R2_Dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

**IIS Authentication Settings**

```
Anonymous Authentication = Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation = Enabled
Forms Authentication = Disabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled
```

**IIS App Pool Settings**

```
Managed Pipeline = Integrated
Identity = htu\srv-htu-iis (domain service account)
```

**Active Directory Settings**

The domain service account htu\srv-htu-iis has had a service principal name set which        associates our site with the account.

Active directory has

```
Allow Delagation to any service
```

SQL Server is running under its own SQL Domain Service account.

**Tests**

I ran the following code tests:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

this correctly return the windows credentials of the user accessing the site

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

return the domain service account "htu\srv-htu-iis" which is what the app pool identity is running under.

Can anyone provide direction as to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Is this a load balanced environment?

Comment: No it isn't (as far as I am aware!)

Comment: Have you looked at this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618552/iis-to-sql-server-kerberos-auth-issues?rq=1  and also this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706580/kerberos-double-hop-in-asp-net-4-0-sql2008r2?rq=1  They cover the topic pretty thoroughly.

Comment: TimG thanks for the posts I missed these despite searching. They have a couple of options for me to try in the morning!

Comment: Excellent documentation - this was our problem: Managed Pipeline = Integrated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well to anyone visiting this question in the future. I resolved this by restarting the IIS Service...doh! Seems my settings were fine just need a full restart of the service!

Comment: @DanielDolz As I understand it, the user visiting the site also has direct access to the SQL Server