# Windows authentication not being passed to SQL Server from IIS (2x on site but separate servers) for ASP.NET MVC web app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

We have a SQL Server on one local server and IIS on another local server. I have a basic ASP.NET MVC web app installed on the server with IIS.

When this app is run locally in VS it shows the users Windows login (though you have to login, it does not automatically pass through - any ideas on how to avoid this would be helpful) and when the user makes CRUD changes to SQL Server, it does this with their user login. This is the expected behavior of the app

However, when the app is hosted in IIS, it does still recognise that the user is logged in (displaying their windows username in the top right) yet the SQL Server is all actioned by the servers own SQL Server login (`DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$`) rather than the users login

I have the application pool identity set to `ApplicationPoolName`. The IIS authentication is set to Windows credentials = enabled with all other options disabled. The Windows credential extended protection is turned off with kernel ticked

I have tried many variations of these settings and this is the best I have achieved. This is my first attempt at this type of thing admittedly, though I am well versed in SQL Server. The connection string clearly works, it is simply that IIS does not seem to pass/delegate the current users window login to SQL, instead passing its own login

I have read and applied many solutions where it simply works for them but none work for me. I have tried allowing impersonation in the asp.net app itself but this causes an error to occur

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: SQL is a _language_, supported by dozens of products: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891605/getting-iis-to-impersonate-the-windows-user-to-sql-server-in-an-intranet-environ . i think `<identity impersonate="true" />` is the ticket

Comment: Ask your domain administrators to guide you through Kerberos delegation configuration and troubleshooting. This isn't a simple thing.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.